# How can I change mapStateToProps to use explicit return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this mapStateToProps and I want to print a console.log(user.isLogged), but I need to change this to use explicit return instead of implicit. How can I change this?

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user, retrospectives }) => (
  {
    userData: user.userData,
    isLogged: user.isLogged,
    organizations: user.organizations,
    retroFinished: retrospectives.retrospective.finished,
    linkToRetro: retrospectives.joinedRetro,
  }
);
```

Comment: `const mapStateToProps = ({ user, retrospectives }) => {
console.log("HERE");
 return  {
    userData: user.userData,
    isLogged: user.isLogged,
    organizations: user.organizations,
    retroFinished: retrospectives.retrospective.finished,
    linkToRetro: retrospectives.joinedRetro,
  }
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use curly braces instead of parens.

Also use a `return` statement.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user, retrospectives }) => {
    return {
      userData: user.userData,
      isLogged: user.isLogged,
      organizations: user.organizations,
      retroFinished: retrospectives.retrospective.finished,
      linkToRetro: retrospectives.joinedRetro,
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `()` use `{}` with a return statement

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user, retrospectives }) => {
  console.log(user);
  return {
    userData: user.userData,
    isLogged: user.isLogged,
    organizations: user.organizations,
    retroFinished: retrospectives.retrospective.finished,
    linkToRetro: retrospectives.joinedRetro,
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ user, retrospectives }) => console.log(user.isLogged) || ({
    userData: user.userData,
    isLogged: user.isLogged,
    organizations: user.organizations,
    retroFinished: retrospectives.retrospective.finished,
    linkToRetro: retrospectives.joinedRetro,
  });
```

Comment: That's still an implicit return.